# latest mvc 3 is redirecting to wrong page on authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, razor

hi i built my site using mvc 3 - RC

i have now installed the lastest mvc3.
i created a new site etc. and now when i run my site that was built with rc, im experiencing an unusual problem.

basically if tries to go to a page that require authentication they are being redirected to

/Account/***LogIn***/?ReturnUrl...

where as in my web.config  i have

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/account/logon" timeout="1" />
</authentication>
```

and it was redirecting fine to th /account/logon page before i created a new mvc3 site.

whats wrong?

Comment: Can you add any routing you have defined for your application?

Comment: there is no routing in global.asax that relates to account/login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was microsoft web helper which i installed as nuget.
infact it broke a whole host of things.

when i removed it along with the webmatrix references the page redirected to the correct page.

really bizzare bug.

Comment: thanks for that, was driving me mad wondering why I was suddenly seeing this behaviour.